# Error - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aee9c6e2_iy62GL.catalog_product_index_price' doesn't exist,

Tags: magento2, database, error, magento2.2.2

I have hosted my website in Nexuss and my website crashed due to a server issue recently. They have replaced my website with the backup and brought back the website.

**Magento version 2.2.2**

But my catalog pages are not working and produce below error. Can anyone help me fix this issue or suggest the best approach?

> 1 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Something went wrong, check and test your Search Engine configurations, reindex catalog and clear cache. Thrown error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aee9c6e2_iy62GL.catalog_product_index_price' doesn't exist,

Comment: Do you mean nexcess hosting?  Have you asked nexcess to assist?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue listed above?